# Why is this code not flagged as potentially violating the code contract?

Tags: c#, char, code-contracts, visual-studio-2013

Maybe I'm not grokking code contracts, but ISTM that this code:

```
private static char GetBarcodeChecksumWithLegacyCode(string barcodeWithoutCzechSum)
{
    Contract.Requires(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(barcodeWithoutCzechSum));
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<char>() != null && Contract.Result<char>().ToString().Trim() != string.Empty); // <-- should fail if length of arg less than 6, which would return a "space" char (' ')

    if (barcodeWithoutCzechSum.Length > 6)
    {
        . . .
        var ch = (char)(48 + b);
        return ch;
    }
    return ' ';
}
```

...which in some cases returns a char of `' '`, which gets converted into an empty string in the "Ensure", doesn't cause the Contract Checker to balk or squawk. Shouldn't it?

### UPDATE

Okay, I was misgrokking what was supposed to be happening with Code Contracts - I thought they would tell me at compile time that my contract was in danger of failing.

In actuality, it is at runtime when they fail that they squawk. When I passed a valid arg to the method, no problem; when I passed it a too-short string, though (less than 6 chars), it told me: "*System.Diagnostics.Contracts.__ContractsRuntime.ContractException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Postcondition failed: Contract.Result().ToString().Trim() != string.Empty*"

Comment: What are you trying to do with `Contract.Result<char>() != null`? How could the result be null when it's a `char`?

Comment: And are you expecting the *static* checker to complain, or for it to fail at execution time?

Comment: As an aside, Czech != check :)

Comment: On a side note, you should use '0' instead of the magic number 48.

Comment: I very much doubt that the static checker will be very 'smart' about `Trim()` and `string.Empty`. A pre-condition about `Length > 6` would seem more to the point but again a Trim() would make it doubtful.